# How to maintain socket connection throughout all activities

Tags: android, service

I have 3 activities in which screenshots of each activity are taken and send to server.Currently I did it with asynctask but I didnt get the output .So, I want to implement it using service.I wrote the Socket connection codes in onStartCommand and called it in activity using startservice.But it didnt work.Is there anybody who have done similar to this.Any kind of help is considered.

Answer (score 0):

you can connect you socket for all activities then connect on Application level class .
This class extends `Application` and do some static method for use all activity

Comment: How can I implement socket ?Asynctask or service

Comment: Is there any examples

Comment: is a simple solution create your own to understand.